# Search WordPress posts with wildcard in a given category for specific sentence and output unique results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

For example I've got the **Metals** category in my WordPress installation with different metals names posted here and there within this category in different posts, like `Metal (brass)`, `Metal (aluminum)` and so on.

What I need is to output all unique mentions of all metals from all posts from that category, skipping specific ones.

As far as I understand, I should create an array with all metal mentions, sort it like I want, keep only unique names and then output the array's content using

```
<?php foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {echo $value.', ';} ?>
```

There is no problem for me to prepare the final array using something like

```
<?php $my_array = array_unique(($metals_array), SORT_REGULAR); ?>
```

but I have no idea how to fill this array with required data, searching posts for `Metal (*)`, and skipping, say, `Metal (steel)` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php 
$title_array = array();
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'metals', 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order'=>'ASC' );
$query = new WP_Query($args); 
if($query->have_posts()): 
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        $title_array[] = get_the_title();
    endwhile; 
endif;
$unique_array = array_unique($title_array);

if($unique_array):
    foreach($unique_array as $unique) {
        echo $unique;
    }
endif;
?>
```

It is the query for simple posts based on category but if you have created a 'Custom Post Type' then the query will be changed, otherwise it will work for you.

'category_name' => 'category-slug'. Category name consists the category slug.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: It is a nice code but it returns post titles, while I need to return something like **We have mentioned Metal (brass), Metal (steel) and Metal (aluminum) across our site**. The problem for me is to fill the array with search results of text found in posts, using wildcards. So that I would only need to search for `Metal (*)` once to get an array filled with `Metal (brass), Metal (steel), Metal (aluminum), Metal (whatever)` and then output this array the way I like.

Comment: May i know the titles?, if the titles are these metal names like Brass, Aluminium,etc. then just add 'Metal()' around the title during creation of array.

Comment: Just like this:-> $title_array[] = "Metal(".get_the_title().")";

Comment: No, the posts titles don't mention **metal** word or its name at all, looking like *Complete guide of making a custom paper-clip* for example. The deal is to find all mentions of a **search term with wildcard** in all posts within a given category and then output all found mentions, (not post titles) as a sentence or list or whatever.